# "Awoken" vs. "awaked"

Tags: word-choice, etymology, verbs, past-participles, wake-waken-awake-awaken

I understand that the verb *awake* has two different past participle forms, *awoken* and *awaked*. Checking Google Ngram I saw that the former has become more popular than the latter in the last century. I want to know two things:

1. Which one would be more used in a casual conversation?
2. Why did this change take place?

Comment: I never heard "awaked", although I did encounter an "awakened" a couple of times in an intransitive meaning.

Comment: As to the first question, "awaked" is archaic. I would not use it in conversation (or anywhere).

Comment: The short story is that the strong verb was (usually) transitive *awake, awoke*, with *awoken* rarer; the weak verb was (originally) intransitive *awaken, awakened*.  But all those have come to be confused. The difference is not one of formality, so “casual conversation” does not apply.  The archaic *awaked* is no longer used, however, because only the strong version has survived.

Comment: Note that both of these are derived from _wake, woke, -----,_ a defective verb for many people, including me. The _-en_ is a causative/inchoative [derivational](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf) suffix, but _-en_ is also a common strong past participle marking (criterial in German, occasional in English).

Comment: @JohnLawler OE had no strong past participle for *wake/woke*, and indeed, we should not have *woke* either. It was formed by analogy with other verbs. OED says: “Apparently the mod. *woke* is a new formation or modification on the analogy of *broke, spoke* ... From the 17th c. onwards the forms *woke, woken* (after *broke, broken, spoke, spoken,* etc.) have been more or less current for the pa. pple.; *woke* seems obsolescent, **but *woken* is at least as frequent as *waked***. No strong forms either of pa. t. or pa. pple. are found in Shaks., the Bible of 1611, or Milton’s verse.”

Comment: (Pok 117) *weg- To be strong, be lively. Oldest form *wegʸ-, becoming *weg- in centum languages.  1. Suffixed o-grade form *wog--. wake, from Old English wacan, to wake up, arise, and wacian, to be awake, from Germanic *wakn. 2. Suffixed o-grade form *wog-no-. waken, from Old English wæcnan, wæcnian, to awake, from Germanic *waknan. 3. watch, from Old English wæccan, to be awake, from Germanic *wakjan. 4. Suffixed form *weg-yo-. Wicca, wicked, witch; bewitch, from Old English wicca, sorcerer, wizard (feminine wicce, witch), from Germanic *wikkjaz, necromancer (< “one who wakes the dead”).

Comment: Related:
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/171832 
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/148744 
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/221905

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## *A Tale of Two Verbs*

### Strong *awake/awoke* vs. weak *awaken/awakened*

The answer is fairly complicated at the detail level, but the short story is that there were two different verbs, one strong (call this the alpha version: *awake, awoke,* and sometimes *awoken*) and the other weak (call this the beta version: *awaken, awakened*).  Both are formed from the original verb, *wake*.

So people got to thinking that *awaken* went to *awoken* the way *awake* went to *awoke*, rather than having *awaken* stay weak and go *awakened*.  They reanalysed *awaken* as a strong verb, the way *awake* had always been.  Then they confused them all.

These two verbs have largely converged, but neither form won out over the other, so both enjoy an uneasy coëxistence such that  different speakers at different epochs elect different versions, sometimes varying it by situation.

Using *had awoken* seems to have replaced the alternate strong form, *had awoke*, around 1929.  The weak form was used by Shakespeare, and still dominates the strong form — although somewhat less so over the last 40 years.  The archaic *had awaked* has been completely replaced by *had awakened* and its alternatives.

---

### Conversationally Speaking

In casual and common conversation, I would probably use the phrasal verb *to wake up*, whether transitively or intransitively, instead of *to awaken*.  Since I am using the *wake* form, I would use the strong-verb inflexions.  I don’t think I use *awaken* at all.

That means that for “casual” conversation, I would myself use the same form there as I would in formal writing.  So with *wake up*:

- Tomorrow, I’ll wake up early.
- Tomorrow, she’ll wake me up before she leaves.
- Yesterday, I woke up early.
- She woke me before the sun came up.
- I’ve woken up early for a year now.
- She hasn’t woken my up that early since we had our fire drill.

Or with *awake*:

- Tomorrow, I’ll awake at dawn.
- Yesterday, I awoke to the sound of a bear getting at my garbage again.
- I’ve never awoken to an alarm in my life.

The only time I might use *awaken* would be intransitively, like:

- Tomorrow, I’ll awaken at dawn.

But I bet I would switch to the other verb for past or past participle, and so use *awoke/awoken*.  For some reason, at least for me, I find that *awoken* calls strongly to supplant *awakened*.  I think I just don’t use *awaken* much.

---

### Thus *spake* the OED

But that’s just me.  These things have changed a bit in the last century or so.
In early days, people would write *had awoke* or *had awaked*, too.  The OED even calls *awoken* “poetical”, but certainly I do hear it in regular speech. I think the recent *awake/awoke/awoken* model is nearly as common as the relatively new *wake/woke/woken* one.

The OED tells the more detailed story here:

> ### **awake** /əˈweɪk/, *v.*
>
> Pa. t. *awoke* /əˈwəʊk/, formerly also *awaked*.
>
> Pa. pple. *awoke* and *awaked*.
>
> **Forms**:
>
> - **ɑ.** (1 *awæcn-an*, see below and cf. *awaken*). 
>   Pa. t. 1-3 *awóc*, 3-4 *awok*, 4 *awook*, (6 Sc. *awoik*), 3- *awoke*. 
>   Pa. pple. 1 *awacen*, 3 *awake*, 7 *awaken*, (poet.) *awoken*, 8- *awoke*.
> - **β.** 1 *awaci-an*, 3 *awaki-en, awakie,* 4 *awaki, -ye,* 4- *awake*, (5 Sc. awalk). 
>   Pa. t. 1 *awacode*, 3-9 *awaked*.
>   Pa. pple. 1 *awacod*, 4- *awaked*.
>
> **Etymology**: In this, as in the simple **wake**, q.v., two early verbs are mixed up; the form-history being complicated with that of *awaken*, as the sense-history is with that of *awecche*.
>
> 1. For the intransitive vb., OE. has *awæcnan, awóc, awacen,* compound of *wæcnan, wóc, wacen,* the present stem having a formative *-n-, wak-n-.* (Cf. Goth. *fraihn-an, frah, fraihans.*) This present began already in OE. to be treated as a weak vb., with pa. t. *awæcnede;* whence mod.E. *awaken, awakened.* As the earliest texts have *onwæcnan*, the *a-* in later OE. was probably = *on-*, not *a-* pref. 1.
> 2. Late OE. had also a weak vb. *awacian, awacode,* in form a compound of *wacian, wacode,* to watch, keep awake, but in sense identical with *awæcnan*, and perhaps originating in a confusion of the two. This gave M. and mod.E. *awake, awaked.*
> 3. After the weak awakened came into common use, as pa. t. of *awaken*, the original relation of awoke and its pa. pple. to that vb. became obscured; and later instinct, in accordance with the general analogies of the language, has referred them to *awake*, treating them as strong equivalents of *awaked*. They are so included here.
> 4. Of all these forms the sense was in OE. only intrans. ‘to arise or come out of sleep,’ the transitive (causal) sense of ‘rouse from sleep’ being expressed by the derivative *awȩcc(e)an,* ME. *awecche*, Goth. *uswakjan*, mod.G. *erwecken*; but soon after 1100 awake began to be used in this sense also, and at length superseded *awecche*, which is not found after 1300. There has been some tendency, especially in later times, to restrict the strong pa. t. and pa. pple. to the orig. intrans. sense, and the weak inflexion to the trans. sense, but this has never been fully carried out.
> 5. The str. pa. pple. *awaken* was already in 13th c. reduced to *awake*, and at length became merely an adjective (mostly predicative), after which a new form from the pa. tense, *awoken*, later awoke was substituted; but the weak *awaked* is also in common use. (Shakspere used only the weak inflexions.)

So it is not the case that *awakened* is somehow a new corruption of the ancient *awoken*.  Both are ancient.  And Shakespeare —  a man who never spelled his own name the same way twice in a row — himself used only the weak inflexions.

I believe than in North America today, *had awoke* would seem “wrong”, as though it used a simple past where a third distinct past participle would be required.  This aversion to things like *had spoke* and *had broke* may have pushed the *had awoken* form into a suppletive position over *had  awoke* in careful writing and speech.

However, there is another verb to consider here than just *to awake*.  There is also *to awaken*.

The OED says:

> ### awaken /əˈweɪk(ə)n/, v.
>
> **Forms:** 1 awæcn-an, 2-5 awakn-en, 3-5 awaken-e(n, 4- awaken.
>
> **Etymology**: OE. *a-wæcn-an*, earlier o*n-wæcn-an*, f. *a-* pref. 2 + *wæcnan*, to waken. For the form-history, and its complication with that of **awake**, see the latter. In OE. *awæcnan* was a str. vb. with pa. t. and pple. *awóc, awacen*. But sometimes the present stem (being irregular) was mistaken for a weak verb, whence already in 9th c. the pa. *awæcnede*, mod. *awakened*, which is now treated as the proper pa. t., while awoke and its accompanying pa. pple. are referred to the originally weak *awake*. Like *awake*, this was also at first strictly intrans.; the transitive use is of comparatively recent appearance, but now (in sense 5) the most frequent.
>
> (In early use, rarely in the literal sense of *awake*; commonly transf. or fig. See senses 2, 3, 5. We still prefer *awaken* to *awake* in sense 5. See also the derivatives below, in which the transferred sense is the usual one in modern use.)

Sense 5 of *awaken* is:

> **5**. *transf*. and *fig*. To rouse into activity; to stir up, excite; kindle (desire, anxiety, interest, attention, etc.); in *Theol*. to arouse to a sense of sin.
>
> - 1603 Shaks. *Meas. for M.* ɪᴠ. ii. 119 ― Lord Angelo··thinking me remisse··awakens mee.
> - 1651 Hobbes *Leviath*. ɪᴠ. xlv. 355 ― To awaken··their Piety and Industry.
> - 1767 Fordyce *Serm. Yng. Wom.* I. i. 11, ― I would··awaken your ambition.
> - 1850 McCosh *Div. Govt.* ɪᴠ. ii. (1874) 499 ― The cry of distress··awakens compassion.

Our modern verb *wake, waked/woke, waked/woke/woken* enjoys — or suffers from — the same historical confusion, and as John Lawler observes, is the original root verb that *awake* and *awaken* derive from.   It was also originally two different verbs, one strong and the other weak.

The OED entry for ***wake*** is even more expansive than on the other two, but it does have one interesting note that is probably relevant here:

> The mod. pa. t. *woke* /wəʊk/ does not regularly represent the OE. *wóc*, which would have yielded *wook* /wʊk/. Apparently the mod. *woke* is a new formation or modification on the analogy of *broke, spoke* (for the irregularity in the vowel cf. *stove* pa. t. of *stave* v.). When this came in is uncertain, for in ME. and prob. in early mod.E. the spelling woke represents the regular phonetic descendant of the OE. *wóc*. The pa. pple *waken* has always been rare, and now survives only in dialects in adjectival use. From the 17th c. onwards the forms *woke, woken* (after *broke, broken, spoke, spoken,* etc.) have been more or less current for the pa. pple.; *woke* seems obsolescent, but *woken* is at least as frequent as *waked*. No strong forms either of pa. t. or pa. pple. are found in Shaks., the Bible of 1611, or Milton’s verse.

Since we have *wake* being reanalysed according to the models of *broke/broken, spoke/spoken*, it makes sense that many writers and speakers by analogy use *wake/woke/woken*, making it more of a “regular” strong verb fitting in with extant models.

---

### So *spoke* the Googlegram

It seems that the formerly heard weak past tense, *awaked*, fell behind the strong past tense *awoke*  around America’s War of Independence.  [N-gram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+awoke%2Che+awaked&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=)

[image: simple past: awaked vs awoke]

Regarding the past participle, *had awoken* took around two hundred more years before it really pulled ahead of *had awoke* by a long shot, although it had been the majority use even before then:  [N-Gram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+awoken%2Chad+awoke&year_start=1948&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image: recent awoken]

So I do not think you had can any longer call *awoken* a “poetic” form.  It seems to have taken the lead around 1929: [N-gram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+awoken%2Chad+awoke&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image: long awoke ngram]

Moreover, there is little difference between the so-called American and British corpora that Google purports to provide: both have just about the same cross-over point for those two.

However, as always with Google N-grams, be careful what you ask about.  For example, if we add the weak verb, *had awakened*, our picture changes quite a bit: [N-gram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+awoken%2Chad+awoke%2Chad+awakened&year_start=1948&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image: awakened ngram]

Whereas [this n-gram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+awoken%2Chad+awoke%2Chad+awakened&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows the longer picture:

[image: awoke long three]

Note that the now-archaic *had awaked* used to be dominant, but now long ago: [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+awoken%2Chad+awoke%2Chad+awakened%2Chad+awaked&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=)

[image: awaked]

Comment: There may be scope for examining transitive and intransitive uses, but it's a big topic.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Agree.  The transitive sense of the weak verb *awaken* is actually new; people always used the strong verb *awake* for transitive things. However, this has now changed and the transitive use of *awaken* dominates today.

Comment: @BarrieEngland The questioner seems to think that all this may have to do with formal writing versus casual conversation. It is much harder to get data on speech, though, than on writing. The OED seems to think transitive *awaken* is now its dominant use.

Comment: The COCA and BNC include spoken data.

Comment: As a not native of the English language, I'm wondering why has no-one felt the need to standardize their roles. But, I know, this doubt no makes sense!

Comment: @Carlo_R. I have no idea how you would go about doing that. You cannot make people talk some way or another.

Comment: The verbs are standardizing themselves (suppletively): *I awoke, I have awakened.* Although I'm not sure where the present tense is going.

Comment: If only your awaken example had been: "Tomorrow, I’ll awaken when I smell bacon.", then this answer would have been perfect.

Answer (score -1):

i prefer awake (present, future tense), awoke (active past tense), awakened (active AND passive past tense). other derivitives, to me, sound awkward.

Comment: Hi, Steveinsandiego, and thanks for your interest in English Language & Usage. Your preferences regarding _awake_ are reasonable—but as presented in your response, they constitute an unsupported comment. I suspect that whoever downvoted your answer did so because it doesn't back up the expression of personal preferences with reference-work corroboration. At this site, answers are supposed to include such corroboration if possible. Comments can be far less formal, but you need to accumulate 50 reputation points on this site before you can leave them beneath other people's questions and answers.