# Past tense of wake: is there a difference between "waked", and "woke"?

Tags: etymology, verbs, differences, past-tense, wake-waken-awake-awaken

I just [stumbled over](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46947/is-the-following-sentence-is-correct-got-up-waked-up/46951?noredirect=1#comment87088_46951) the verb "to wake", which according to [various](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/wake) [sources](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wake) has two valid forms for the past tense: "woke" and "waked".

Some [further research](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wake) stated, that there seem to be two (Old / Middle) English verbs - one strong, one weak - today's "wake" stems from, hence the *two* forms for past tense:

- [waken](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/waken), meaning to *cease* to sleep and
- [wakien](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wakien), meaning to *stay* awake, keep watch

Now, as there are *two* origins, I'm wondering: 
**Are there (subtle?) differences in meaning when using "woke" or "waked" today?**

Comment: "woken" is by far the most used in England. In fact, I'm pretty sure most children would be corrected when using "waked".

Comment: @JamesWorld though if they said they'd woken their recently dead grandmother instead of waked her, the claim would become quite different.

Comment: @JonHanna True - although it's valid, I can't recall ever hearing "waked" used in that sense. I can only ever recall it being used as a noun, as in, "There was a wake for my grandmother."

Comment: @JamesWorld it's rare now (the OED lists it as "Now only dial., chiefly Anglo-Irish.") but some north English dialects would be among the set that were "chiefly" Irish.

Comment: I'm not surprised, wakes are a much bigger part of Irish culture than in England, Scotland and Wales.

Comment: @JamesWorld and yet apparently originally an English thing (north of the Danelaw) before it was an Irish thing.

Comment: @JonHanna I always thought the Irish _faire_ was sort of proof that it was an old thing in Ireland … but looking it up now, it turns out that’s just one of those endless secondary initial f’s that pop up during Middle Irish, being basically the same word as _aire_, a direct calque from _wake/watch_. Boo. :-(

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet why *boo*? That *faire* is from the English *wake* and *crack* (or if you must use the 1970s tourist-money-targeted spelling, *craic*) is from English *crack* doesn't impinge on the well-earned reputation of our wakes for having the best crack.

Comment: @JonHanna It’s just a bit duller than a true, inherited etymology. Loan words are useful for many things (especially timing of sound laws), but they’re rarely all that interesting, not to me anyway.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ah now, *crack* has a fascinating etymology taking in Shakespearean insults, later African-American insults and the Irish having a good time in one etymological tale, while *wake* shows the movement of the tradition from the Vikings in Scandinavia to the the North English territories and from there to become one of the most distinct cultural features of Ireland. Loan words often come with a lot of wider history.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/91114
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/171832 
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/148744

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is rather a knotty little group of verbs that have gone all over the place in Modern English, though they were very clearly and regularly distinguished in Old English.

Let’s start with the etymology, and then move on to current usage.

### Etymology

The words *watch*, *(a)wake*, *(a)waken* all share a common root. The Proto-Indo-European root was **u̯eǵ-*, and its basic meaning approximately ‘to be strong/quick/lively/aroused/powerful’. It underlies for example Sanskrit वाजः *vā́ jaḥ* ‘power/force’, Latin *vigil* ‘watchful/awake’ (as in English *vigil* also), *vigere* ‘be lively’ (as in *vigorous* in English), *velox* ‘fast/lively’ (from **veg-lox*; as in *velocity* in English).

In Proto-Germanic, the root regularly became **wek-*, with the ablaut form **wak-*. This latter form generally took over, because it was found in a very common construction with this root: the causative (PIE) **u̯oǵ-ei̯e-* > (PG) **wak-ja-* ‘make lively’ = ‘awaken [someone], wake [someone] up’. So for all practical purposes, the Germanic root was **wak-*.

There were then at least three different verbs derived straight from this root present in Proto-Germanic (note: **-aną-* is the reconstructed Proto-Germanic infinitive marker):

1. A simple verb **wak-aną-*, retaining the original meaning of the basic root, ‘be lively/awake’
2. A nasal inchoative<sup>1</sup> **wak-n-aną-*, meaning ‘become awake’ = ‘wake up [by oneself]’
3. The causative **wak-j-aną-* mentioned above, meaning ‘make lively/awake’ = ‘wake [someone] up, awaken [someone]’

These were all quite regular, since both the causatives and inchoatives were regularly formed in Germanic by adding the **-j-* and **-n-* suffixes.

In Old English, they were also relatively distinct, although some parts of the paradigms had already started to coalesce. Most notably, both the old base verb and the old inchoative verb had become strong verbs in verbal class VI. This is original to the base verb (which is a primary, non-derived verb and therefore shows ablaut—the Proto-Indo-European equivalent of Germanic strong verbs), but not to the inchoative verb. The inchoative verb is a derived one, and it ought to have been weak; but it had fallen together with the base verb in the past tense.

This coalescence is very clear if you look at the Wiktionary paradigms for [Old English *wacan*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wacan#Old_English) and [Old English *wæcnan*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/w%E6cnan#Old_English): the past tense forms are the same, the others are distinct.

The causative **wak-j-aną-*, on the other hand, had maintained its different conjugation throughout: it remained a weak verb of class II, [Old English *wacian*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wacian#Old_English).

So at a brief glance, if we give just the third person singular of the three verbs in Old English:

1. *Wacan*: present *wæceþ*, past *wōc*
2. *Wæcnan*: present *wæcneþ*, past *wōc*
3. *Wacian*: present *wacaþ*, past *wacode*

In Middle English, when final syllables started being reduced and lost, the differences between these three paradigms started getting muddled. The Middle English infinitive forms are the ones you have found on Wiktionary yourself:

1. *Waken*
2. *Waknen*
3. *Wakien*

Once the forms started getting muddled, obviously the meanings started to overlap—it’s difficult, after all, to maintain a difference between ‘becoming [by one’s own accord] awake’ and ‘causing [someone] to be awake’ and ‘being awake’ when half of them have the same shape in various forms in the paradigm.

### Current verbs

In current English, there are only two basic forms left: *wake* and *waken*.

*Wake* is, in form, basically from the old base verb *waken* < *wacan*. The modern verb *waken*, on the other hand, is from the inchoative *waknen* < *wæcnan*. Note that in both these words, it is the final *-en* that has been lost over time, and modern *waken* thus represents Middle English *wakn*, to which of course an extra little prop vowel was added, since /kn/ is not a valid way to end a syllable in English.

In Middle English (as in Old English), both *waken* and *waknen* generally had a strong past form, *wook* (in various spellings), which is what gives modern *woke*. The weak causative *wakien* had a weak past, *waked(e)*. When the form of the causative was mostly lost (merging with the base verb once *-en* disappeared), the weak past was kept in some dialects, the strong past in others, and both in yet others.

On the other hand, the inchoative *waknen* developed a new weak past of its own, *wakned(e)* and stopped using *wook* like the base/causative verb. So there was a shift in what verbs shared what past tense forms:

- [base + inchoative] strong past *vs.* [causative] weak past >
  [base + causative] strong or weak (or both) past *vs.* [inchoative] weak past

This is the reason why *waken* today has only a weak past form, *wakened*, while *wake* can have both strong *woke*<sup>2</sup> and weak *waked*.

When the causative disappeared as a separate form, the rather unusual thing happened that its semantics were taken over not only by the base verb (with which it merged in form), but *also* by the inchoative verb. This means that both the base verb and the inchoative verb can now be either transitive or intransitive, which is a messy situation, but reality.

### *Waked* vs. *woke* in current usage

In current English, *woke* is the standard past tense of *wake*, both transitive and intransitive, causative or not; *waked* is marked as nonstandard (dialectical) or archaic, and it’s nowhere near as common as *woke*.

An exception to this is when *wake* is not the inherited verb(s) discussed above, but rather a different verb derived (through normal zero-derivation) from a noun. *Wake* as a noun has at least two common meanings (etymologically unrelated): a vigil after the death of someone; and the trail of water or air left behind a vessel. When either of these nouns is used as a verb, the verb is a secondary, derived one, and such verbs are (nearly) always weak.

That means that the local community *waked* old Mrs. Smith last week after she passed away; you would never say that they **woke* her. Similarly, you might possibly say that the ferry *waked* its way through the narrow strait; but certainly never in a million years that it **woke* its way.
*(Thanks to @supercat for mentioning this in the comments below.)*

---

<sup>1</sup> There’s quite a bit of discussion about what the exact usage of these nasal formations were in Common Germanic. They are often based on nouns describing people or jobs, and they then mean ‘do/behave as X does’, a basically causative or factitive meaning; thus, in Old English, we get *læcnian* ‘heal’ from *lǣċe* ‘doctor’. But they are also used more or less as inchoatives from adjectives, as *blacken* ‘become black’ from *black*.

<sup>2</sup> As Jon mentions both in his answer and a comment here, *woke*, phonemically /woʊk/, is not quite regular from the Old English *wóc*. Some analogy with similar-sounding verbs like *break*, *speak*, and *steal* (which did sound the same earlier on, though they’re different now) took place at some point. Middle English *wook* or *wooke* or *woke* can be regular from *wóc*, assuming that they represent /wuk/, which is what the Old English form should give—but that’s not necessarily a given, considering the vagaries of Middle English spelling.

Comment: The OED claims that *woke* had nothing to do with the original strong form, but was a Modern English innovation.

Comment: @JonHanna I’m not so sure they’re quite right about that. _Wook_ does occur as a dialect past tense (“I wook him up” rhyming with “I shook him up” is definitely something I’ve heard), and while it’s clearly true (as per your Ngram) that _woke_ was much less common literally for a good while, I think it at least as likely that _woke_ is a reshaping of the old strong past, rather than a completely new strong paradigm built from a purely weak one after the previous strong one was lost.

Comment: Such completely new strong forms most certainly happen, and as such certainly could have happened here. It would be fascinating (and alas probably impossible to prove) to know if such *wook* pronunciations did indeed go back to the original *wook* and then later either influenced the new *woke* or (more interesting still, to my mind) got newly-interpreted as a pronunciation of a genuinely new form.

Comment: While the normal verb usage of the verb "wake" relates to being or becoming awake, other usages listed relate to holding a wake or vigil.  I would suggest that the latter usage should use "waked" as the past tense, in a fashion somewhat analogous to the the usage of the verb "fly" meaning "to hit a fly ball".  If Mr. Slugger hit a fly ball to left field one would say that he "flied" out to left field, not that he "flew" there.  Although using "flied" as the past tense for most usages of "fly" would be incorrect, for some usages it would be required.

Comment: @supercat You’re absolutely correct in that (this was also discussed in the comments to the question itself). Derived verbs are nearly always weak, and _wake_ (as well as _fly_) in this sense isn’t really the same verb as the _wake_ I’m talking about here: it’s a denominative derived from the noun _wake_. That’s why I didn’t mention it. If you zero-derive a verb meaning ‘enable to bend/stretch under pressure’ from the noun _give_ and put that in the past tense, you would also say that you ‘gived’ the fabric, rather than ‘gave’ the fabric.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I think it's important to note that the existence of a past-tense form a verb doesn't mean that past tense form is correct for the verb's common usage.  I would have guessed that "to cause a track of waves [to disturb]" would be more likely zero-derivation than "to hold a vigil for", though Dictionary.com only lists the latter.

Comment: @supercat I’ve added a couple of paragraphs about derived verbs at the end.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Looks good.  It would be interesting indeed, if, in the process of waking the deceased Mrs. Smith, the community woke her.

Comment: @supercat if they'd waked their dead brother any louder, they would have woke the dead.

Answer (score 8):

[Garner’s Usage Tip of the Day: Miscellaneous Entries.](http://www.lawprose.org/blog/?p=2804) seems to indicate that the preferred choice between the alternative forms of the past participles 'waked' and 'woken' is determined purely geographically. It is probable that the choice of past simple reflects this to a limited degree, though Garner does not list 'waked' as a 'preferred' choice:

> **wake**; **awake**; **awaken**.
>
> The past-tense and past-participial forms of “wake” and its various
>   siblings are perhaps the most vexing in the language. Following are
>   the preferred declensions:
>
> “wake / woke / waked (or woken)”;
>
> “awake / awoke / awaked (or awoken)”;
>
> “awaken / awakened / awakened”;
>
> “wake up / woke up / waked up.”
>
> For the past participle, American English prefers “waked”; British
>   English prefers “woken.”

The erroneous claim that 'waked' is not an acceptable past participle of 'wake', by a 'senior member' (sound shift) at [WordReference.co](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2699650), shows that the acceptability / idiomaticity of the usages of these verbs cause quite a lot of disagreement.

Another senior member there (morior_invictus) (and I thought the usernames here were outlandish) says:

> I have seen "waked" as the past tense of "wake" in American English,
>   but "I have just waked up." sounds incorrect to me as well.
>
> I would accept "I just woke up." (i.e. a simple past) or "I just waked
>   someone up." but not "I just waked up." It doesn't sound good to me.

I agree that transitive vs intransitive usage makes a difference to idiomaticity, perhaps even acceptability. The US - UK divide is also an important factor.

Comment: +1, I find this answer much more useful than the Janus' answer, as it focuses on the actual question: "Are there (subtle?) differences in meaning when using "woke" or "waked" *today*?" I'm surprised by the claim that "American English prefers 'waked'", as I would definitely correct someone who used it.

Comment: It would be (I almost said 'wrong'!) inappropriate in my opinion to 'correct' them, as an authority on usage, and various dictionaries, license the forms. I do agree that the 'waked' forms are (probably in the US, and almost certainly in the UK,) very unusual, and have idiosyncratic distributions (*/??I waked up at ...). I'd certainly advise people to use the less outlandish-sounding forms.

Comment: I phrased that poorly. I meant to say that I would have corrected them prior to reading these answers, as I was previously unaware that anyone would consider 'waked' correct usage. This was meant to make clear how surprised I am to hear that this other usage is acceptable. At this point I would do as you have described, and point out that that usage sounds rather strange, even if some would consider it acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

> Some further research stated, that there seem to be two (Old / Middle) English verbs - one strong, one weak - today's "wake" stems from, hence the two forms for past tense:

This appears to be irrelevant, but that it is is actually more interesting than if it isn't, because we'd actually expect this dual-form to happen here, because *wæcnan* was a strong verb and *wacian* a weak verb.

"Strong verb" would mean the sort of verb that has the *woke* and *woken* forms, with the sort of verb that has a *waked* form being correspondingly referred to as a "weak verb". This use of *strong* and *weak* coming from Jacob Grimm's writings on Germanic languages (including English).

So, all things being equal, we'd not be surprised at this dual form. Notably, the OED tells us:

> In Middle English the strong and weak forms came to be used indiscriminately in both senses.

So, at this point there were two ways of saying the verb in the past tense, but no semantic difference between them.

However, the OED claims:

> The modern past tense woke /wəʊk/ does not regularly represent the Old English wóc , which would have yielded wook /wʊk/ . Apparently the modern woke is a new formation or modification on the analogy of broke , spoke (for the irregularity in the vowel compare stove past tense of stave v.). When this came in is uncertain, for in Middle English and probably in early modern English the spelling woke represents the regular phonetic descendant of the Old English wóc. The past participle waken has always been rare, and now survives only in dialects in adjectival use. From the 17th cent. onwards the forms woke, woken (after broke, broken, spoke, spoken, etc.) have been more or less current for the past participle; woke seems obsolescent, but woken is at least as frequent as waked. No strong forms either of past tense or participle are found in Shakespeare, the Bible of 1611, or Milton's verse.

So there was a *woke* that was more like *wook*, but it died out to leave *waked*, but then people produced a *woke* by analogy to how the rhyming *break* has a *broke*.

Indeed, we can see a suggestion of this *wook* form in the spelling used in:

> Grete lordes riste toke, & nyghte wache full worthily wooke. — *Duke Rowland and Sir Otuell* ca 1400

For a strong verb to become a weak one (that is, to become one that we use *-ed* with) is very common. A lot of our current weak verbs were strong verbs in Old English. This is understandable since we all know the general rule about adding *-ed* to a verb, but have to learn the other forms, not least because they've become increasingly irregular over the centuries. It's not hard to see how people would apply *-ed* to verbs that previously did not take it, and that would eventually become the form everyone used.

For a weak verb to become strong is less common, but does still often happen. [This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/104015/15770) has more information on that.

This claim by the OED would explain the history of use we can see here:
[image]

As always, take ngrams with a pinch of salt (and alas they become almost completely useless once you go back another century which is where we would most want to see the history), but it does amount to additional evidence.

So if you'd asked this question five hundred years ago, the answer would indeed have been "because there are two source Old English words", but in since then the verb has managed to first lose one of its past-tense forms, and then later acquire another!

> Are there (subtle?) differences in meaning when using "woke" or "waked" today?

As noted in the answer I linked to, sometimes when we have this dual-past phenomenon one of them becomes more heavily used in some senses.

Here, of those senses that relate to keeping a watch *waked* remains more common, while *woke* is more common in terms of transitioning from sleep to wakefulness.

The sense about stopping sleeping is in itself much more common than the other senses anyway, and hence *woke* more common generally, but in areas where it is still common to say that you *waked* someone as in you hosted or attended their wake after they died (a sense now mostly only found in Ireland though still sometimes found in Scotland and England, particularly the north) it would be very unusual to use *woke* while for a living person whose sleep you disturbed *woke* would be more common but *waked* would still be heard.

That the sense I just mentioned is rare in most of the English-speaking world is likely relevant. To quote the OED again:

> but in the modern English period the static sense, both intransitive and transitive, has become almost obsolete, the usual meanings of the word being ‘to become or cause to become awake’.

It is likely precisely because these senses are now rare or even archaic in most dialects that one does not use the more recent *woke* with them; in most dialects it would only be used in a deliberately old-fashioned manner, and in the few remaining other cases it just didn't acquire this new *woke* in that sense.

This distinction is not so sharp as to be anything close to "a rule", again because the relative rarity of these other senses today would prevent a strong sense of "this is the correct way" emerging.